# GET запрос выдает ошибку (NODE.JS)

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, get

взял с документации вот такой код:

```
const axios = require('axios')
console.log(axios.get('http://ident.me/'));
```

проблема в том что вместо результата запроса я получаю `Promise { <pending> }`, как можно решить эту проблему?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`axios.get` асинхронная функция, поэтому тебе возвращается Promise. Чтобы дождаться завершения функции, добавь `await`

```
(async function() {
    const axios = require('axios')
    console.log(await (axios.get('http://ident.me/')));
})()
```

Comment: ваш ответ выдает ошибку: SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Comment: Скобку забыл, исправил

Comment: а теперь выдает ReferenceError: await is not defined

Comment: Код где запускается? Это встроенная функция, она должна быть https://learn.javascript.ru/async-await

Comment: в cmd через node file.js

Comment: Изменил код, попробуй еще раз

Comment: спасибо, а не подскажите как из него можно извлечь data в которой записан ip человека?

Comment: Если ответ помог, то нажмите на галочку, чтобы пометить как решение. Для второго вопроса, лучше задать отдельный вопрос с подробностями того, что возвращает вам сервер